# knockout clear and clone array

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to clear and clone a knockout array in an if statement.  first click it works fine.  after that it keeps adding to the array and not removing it. So the ee_pp_summarylist keeps growing with additional clicks instead of clearing and loading the other.

```
if ($("#idee").prop("class") == "detail") {
    $("#idee").removeClass("detail").addClass("full");
    $("#idee").val("Collapse");
    self.ee_pp_summarylist.removeAll();
    self.ee_pp_summarylist(self.ee_pp_summarylist_detail.slice(0));
}
else {
    $("#idee").removeClass("full").addClass("detail");
    $("#idee").val("Detail");
    self.ee_pp_summarylist.removeAll();
    self.ee_pp_summarylist(self.ee_pp_summarylist_ag.slice(0));
}
```

Added a fiddle.  Works in the fiddle but not in my project. figures....
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8Vdd/)

I've checked the length in self.ee_pp_summarylist does reflect correctly. but the screen still isn't changing correctly.

figured it out.
data-bind="tablesort: ee_pp_summarylist" a custom binding I was using to utilize tablesorter plugin.

Comment: Maybe try to reproduce in a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out.
data-bind="tablesort: ee_pp_summarylist" a custom binding I was using to utilize tablesorter plugin.